# When to check for nullptr inside functions with a pointer parameter?

Tags: c, pointers

Coming from C++ where we have `const` references I always struggle to solve this in C.

If I have something like this in C:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x,y,z;
};

void test(struct Vector3 *va, struct Vector3 *vb) {

    // Check for nullptr... 
    if (va == NULL || vb == NULL) {
       // log / exit program
    }
    // bla bla...
}
```

In C++ I can use a `const` reference to not allow a NULL pointer but not in C. When do you check for null in your functions? Or what rules do you use to check or not check? Because it feels wrong to check in every function that receives a pointer if the pointer is null or not.

I know that I can pass the value of the `Vectors` instead of pointers but this is only an example. Suppose that we are dealing with big structs.

Comment: Personally I will `NULL` check an parameter only when some other part of the function could logically execute without it. I'll usually also assert the validity of pointers i'm expecting to be valid. I think a lot of it comes down to style and documentation. Unfortunately you do lose the absolute right to assume pointer validity, you just have to make up for it with common sense, and trust your function caller to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between a logic error and an assertion error. If your function is only allowed to run with a valid pointer, then the user of your function is responsible and should check if it's a valid pointer before entering your function. Standard C functions document such states as "undefined behavior", because it's literally undefined how `strcpy(NULL, "abc")` should react - passing such values to functions is just invalid and the programmer (other code) is responsible to check for such errors.

If so, this is where `assert()` comes in play. `assert` was intended to fire only in debug configuration of your project and to be removed (so that performance is not hindered) in a release configuration of your project - hence `NDEBUG` macro. [NASA principles of safety-critical code](https://books.google.pl/books?id=j7wpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=nasa+assertions+per+code&source=bl&ots=MGfMwTyKr3&sig=ACfU3U2hg4V9wV5Ibhm6AlnaVYbdOFGQIA&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv-56hzcPqAhW2wsQBHaugD8MQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=assert&f=false) tells "code's assertion density should average to minimally two assertions per functions".

So if passing NULL to your function is an "invalid state" in which case the behavior of your function is "not defined", because it just doesn't make sense to pass NULL (or any other invalid pointer), I usually write:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x,y,z;
};

void test(struct Vector3 *va, struct Vector3 *vb) {
    assert(va != NULL);
    assert(vb != NULL);
    // bla bla...
}
```

(and on gcc I would add `__attribute__((__nonnull__))` and with newest gcc with `-std=c2x` we can `[[gnu::nonnull]]`). Be aware that `assert()` expands to "nothing" when `NDEBUG` is defined (ie. the expression is not evaluated), so do not put statements with side effects inside `assert()`.

Comment: Aha, then adding the assert will help to debug errors in debug mode if the user passes a nullptr but will be undefined behavior (no performance penalty) if it happens in release, makes sense. I'm accepting this answer because I think it's the more complete and with an example.

Answer (score 4):

If the function promises (in its documentation) to handle null pointers, it needs to check. Otherwise it doesn't and when a user then (erroneously) provides a null pointer to such a function, the behavior becomes undefined.

You can let the compiler help you enforce such contracts by declaring the pointer argument that doesn't accept null pointers as
`type arg[static 1]` (no diagnostic required, but clang does warn when you pass `NULL` through such arguments) rather than `type *arg` or by using the nonstandard `__attribute((nonnull(arg_index)))` function attribute (results in a diagnostic when you pass `NULL` through such arguments), but these are not required for correctness.

`assert`s (that get elided in release builds) can be helpful too.

Comment: For `type arg[static 1]` arg, compiler doesn't "enforce" that it's non-null; it's simply an *indication* tto the compiler that non-null arg isn't passed. No diagnostic is required if a null pointer is passed to such a function.

Comment: @P.P. Thanks for the comment. Yes, diagnostics for passing `NULL` through `type arg[static N]`  are entirely optional. `clang` warns about this, gcc doesn't (both have attribute nonnull, which warns about it reliably).

Comment: The same is applicable for `nonnull` attribute, too. If the compiler can't deduce that it's non-null argument, no warnings will be issued (besides, it being a compiler extension). In short, neither is a **replacement** for null pointer validation. And so their practical use is limited as you'd still need a null pointer check anyway in nearly all cases.

Comment: Might not hurt to include static code analysis into the process to further detect dereferencing of NULL pointers.

Comment: @P.P Yes, it only warns about statically known null pointers. But the route where you simply trigger UB if a provided pointer is null is perfectly valid. C is fraught with possibilities of UB. I don't see people checking for overflow in every signed math operations, boundchecking every subscript etc. when context can guarantee correctness without the cost of the check. Everything's a trade-off.

Comment: @P.P Do you know what the compiler does with the information from the `[static ...]`?  If there's no diagnostic required, I imagine there must be something else interesting it does with that information.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons `type arg[static N]` lets the compiler know that (at least) `N` items are definitely accessible. That can help codegen, I hear. It also implies `arg!= (void*)0` which is why clang takes it to also mean attribute nonnull.

Comment: @PSkocik I was curious in what way it helps with code-gen.  What kind of optimizations can be made when assuming that there are at least N elements in the array.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons From what I can tell, it's practically useless. But I have [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62843710/1275169) in case anyone can clarify or know its purpose.

Comment: From the linked question, there *is* a practical advantage (optimization). But it's not the "size guarantee"' or non-null guarantee/check.

Answer (score 3):

When writing in C, I usually take the C approach: *document* requirements on function arguments, and assume that the caller provides arguments that conform with the documentation.  Thus, if I document that a pointer argument must be a valid pointer to a `struct Vector3` (for example), I typically don't perform a null check, simply letting the chips fall where they may if the caller does not comply.

For cases where you would or could use specifically a `const` reference in C++, you also have the alternative of passing structures, unions, and scalars (but not arrays) by value.  For small structures, such as those in your example, that might even produce a minor performance boost in some cases.  Example:

```
void test(struct Vector3 va, struct Vector3 vb) {
    // bla bla...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets agree about this: if a NULL pointer is passed to a function and dereferenced inside it, the program causes a *segmentation fault* (or a CPU nullptr exception if you are working with an embedded uC - it can have a different name depending on the specific device). That's something that we usually don't like.

We cannot prevent the caller to pass *invalid* pointers, but with this check we can at least prevent a good percentage of potential crashes.

Let's summarize the main scenarios:

1. **We want to check** when our function is an API we deliver to third parties. Someone has to do the check, and since we cannot be sure that the customer will write safe code, we check the parameters and return an error in case of invalid values. *(As an exception, we could actually have a well documented API in which the customer is warned that a NULL parameter will result in a crash).*
2. **We can check or not** if our function is an utility we use in our own program (e.g an embedded firmware). We designed our code, so we could have decided that the parameters validity check is **always** in charge of the caller (in this case we don't check) or that it is always in charge of the called function  (in this case we don't check).
3. **We can avoid checking** if we are so confident about our design that we are sure that every function call will have valid parameter. Or alternatively when the flash memory of our embedded SW is so limited in space that we need to save all the extra code coming from those `if (ptr != NULL)` checks. In the latter case, even a system restart could be acceptable.

Comment: An important question to be considered is what to do instead of crashing if the arguments are invalid.  I am having trouble coming up with a scenario where passing an invalid or (unexpectedly) null pointer argument results from anything other than a programming error, so it is in no way clear that there will be any viable recovery path.

Comment: `the program crashes` I have strange feeling that I will not agree with that. I will agree that an implementation/architecture dependent signal will happen. But not necessarily "crash".

Comment: @JohnBollinger in this case there's the quite typical BADPARAM error (or something like that). Even the "trace error and do nothing" option is better than a crash. Ps: in my company, that designs cellular iot devices, the check is in charge of the called function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I like to set `errno` to `EINVAL` and potentially return a value indicating an error.  At the very least, it will help the poor sucker in the future that has to debug it.  Hopefully other programmers heed that error when they call the function and log it or something so it can more easily be traced.

Comment: @kamilcuk I've coded for Windows, Linux (a segfault is a crash, isn't it?) and several embedded OSes, and dereferencing a null pointer would always lead to a program abnormal termination. What an I missing? Is the term "crash" the problem? I can change it.

Comment: Well, then you missed that part, where dereferencing NULL on linux causes to send `SIGSEGV` signal, which can be handled and in signal context code continues execution. It's not a "crash", it's a signal. And, well, dereferencing NULL on stm32 causes a HardFault exception. That's not a "crash", just code jumps to different location. I'll agree that something will happen, but that's not necessarily a crash.

Comment: @kamilcuk I understand your point. In our (probably inaccurate) slang, we group these scenarios under the word "crash". I'm aware of CPU nullptr exceptions. But I've never seen it handled differently to a system restart. It is a situation that in many applcations simply must not happen. I'll change the word crash. ;)

Answer (score 0):

General rule is that if you are going to dereference the pointer, then you check that it's not a null pointer for obvious reasons.

Where exactly you do that depends on what the function does and whether the pointer is central to its functionality. If you're *always* going to dereference it, then it makes sense to check at the beginning. E.g.

```
void func(mytype *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) return;

    /* important stuff */
}
```

or

```
void func(mytype *ptr)
{
    if (ptr) {
        /* important stuff */
     }
}
```

If it's sort of an "optional" thing, then you can check at the "point of use", such as:

```
void func(mytype *ptr)
{
    /* important stuff that's always done */

    /* Optionally, if the ptr is not null, set it */
    if (ptr) {
        *ptr = /* a value that indicates some status or a calculated result */;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Any parameter validation should go at the beginning of the function, so you can avoid accidentally using arguments before they're validated.

In C there are no standard compiler guarantees that something is not null (unlike C++ references), so you cannot know for sure. If you know that only you will be calling some function, you could consolidate your input checking so you don't have to do it multiple times for the same pointer as it passes through different functions. But for pointers/code that come from libraries, there are no guarantees, so if you want to avoid segfaults you have to check everywhere.

Comment: So are you saying that each function that receives a pointer parameter should check for null?

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that your function is always called with the address of a `struct Vector3` variable, normally, you don't have to check if it's equals `NULL`.

Otherwise, you have to check and define the actions to do in this case.

If you have for example a recurive function that go through a binary tree, you have to check if root node is not NULL, because even if the first call had a not NULL pointer, after calling the same function many times, you could/will have this case where the function is called with a NULL pointer.