# On the practical advantage to C99's array size "guarantee" feature in function parameters?

Tags: c, static, language-lawyer, c99

C99 introduced a new function argument notation where the `static` keyword can be used to specify that the argument has at least N elements.

[6.7.6.3 Function declarators, p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7)

> A declaration of a parameter as ''array of type'' shall be adjusted to
> ''qualified pointer to type'', where the type qualifiers (if any) are
> those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If
> the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type
> derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
> corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
> element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
> size expression.

E.g.

```
void func(int x[static 10])
{
    /* something */
}
```

says that x has at least 10 elements. But this is not a constraint and as such a compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic.

The [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) on this states:

> [..] It would be a significant advantage on some systems for the
> translator to initiate, at the beginning of the function, prefetches
> or loads of the arrays that will be referenced through the parameters.
> There is no way in C89 for the user to provide information to the
> translator about how many elements are guaranteed to be available.
>
> In C99, the use of the static keyword in:

```
void fadd(double a[static 10], const double b[static 10]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0.0)
            return;
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
    return;
}
```

> guarantees that both the pointers a and b provide access to the first
> element of an array containing at least ten elements. The static
> keyword also guarantees that the pointer is not NULL and points to an
> object of the appropriate effective type.

The rationale appears to suggest stronger guarantees than what's stated in the C standard.

Based on these facts:

- Are there any practical systems where this provides "significant advantages" as stated in the rationale?
- Why does the C standard make no such guarantees (as in the C99 rationale) that might have motivated the introduction of this feature in the first place?

(Obviously, better compile time diagnostics could be one use - but that's neither a "significant advantage" nor does it help optimizations as intended. Besides, compilers
can always issue diagnostics if they deduce potential null pointer dereferencing without a formal feature like this).

Comment: You state that C99 makes no such guarantees, despite the rationale's assertion that it does.  So either the rationale is wrong, or your interpretation of the C99 standard is wrong.

Comment: And there's no shortage of [articles on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=clang+c99+static+array+parameter) that make the same claim as the rationale.  So again, either your interpretation of the standard is wrong, or those folks didn't get the memo.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As linked in the question, the C standard specifies no such constraints. While the rationale is written by the same folks involved in the standard, it isn't as authoritative as the normative text in the standard. I haven't gone all the articles from your seach-link, but the top two agrees with my interpretation of the standard.

Comment: Then perhaps the things you think ought to be in the standard simply didn't pass muster with the standards committee, rationale notwithstanding.

Comment: Why do you say “The rationale appears to suggest stronger guarantees than what's stated in the C standard.” The rationale says use of the `static` keyword in its example “guarantees that both the pointers a and b provide access to the first element of an array containing at least ten elements.” The standard text you quote says “If the keyword static also appears …, then … the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.” How is the standard wording not at least as strong?

Comment: Similarly, the rationale says “The static keyword also guarantees that the pointer is not NULL and points to an object of the appropriate effective type.” This too appears to be covered by the words in the standard: A null pointer would not provide access to ten elements. I suppose you could argue that the standard merely says the argument has to provide access to ten elements of “an” array, not necessarily an array of the specified type, whereas the rational says the type has to match. Is that what you are getting at?

Comment: I read the rationale's "guanrantees that pointer is not NULL" as something that'll be enforced by the compiler (diagnostic; whereas the standard doesn't require that.

Comment: I think you are just misunderstanding who's making the "guarantee" in the rationale.  It's a commitment made by the programmer to the compiler, and not the other way around.  The compiler will rely on the programmer's word, even if the compiler can't prove that it's always kept, but at the penalty of runtime UB if it's broken.  It's the anti-Ronald Reagan: "Trust but don't verify".

Comment: Indeed, with a little thought, it should be clear there's no way the compiler could possibly verify that all calls to the function satisfy the guarantee, without making the feature so restrictive it would be unusable.  As R. points out, the compiler may not even *see* the `static` value when it compiles a call to the function, since the `static` annotation needn't be in the declaration.

Comment: And even if it could, imagine `int *p = malloc(fetch_size() * sizeof(int)); func(p);`.  The compiler can't see the code of `fetch_size()` and has no way of knowing whether it always returns a number larger than 10, even if the programmer knows for sure this is the case.  So for your interpretation of the rationale to be right, such code would have to be unconditionally rejected.  I can't imagine that's what anyone intended.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think, like you said, I may have misinterpreted the "guarantee" from whom to whom in the rationale (the standard is clear on this). But the still, the question on feature's utility stands. As R. said, it's basically limited to optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't entirely follow your question, but I think you may be confused about what the lack of a "constraint" here entails. It's not a constraint, and the compiler is not obligated to issue a diagnostic, because the compiler is not necessarily able to see the definition of the function at the point(s) of call(s) to it. The `static` array-size guarantee is a property of the function *definition*, not the function *type*/*declaration*. There are various possible reasons for this, the most likely being a desire not to make declarations with/without it incompatible function types.

Unfortunately, this limits the feature to being used only for *optimization*, not *correctness checking*, except in cases where the compiler (or linker) can see the mismatch. The "advantage" of the feature is that the compiler can make optimizations that read indices that would not be read on the abstract machine. For example, in:

```
int foo(int a, int b[static 1])
{
    if (!a) return 0;
    else return a & *b;
}
```

the branch can be optimized out.

Comment: I have edited the title. The questions are in the description (hopefully it's clear). To paraphrase: 1) what the "significant advantage" that's claimed in the rationale? 2. If the standard waters down the "guarantees" (compared with the rationale) due to implementation considerations, is there any real advantage to using it in today's implementations?

Comment: Apple Clang 11.0.0 building for x86_64 makes this optimization. The code generated without `static 1` has a `testl` and `je` that the code with `static 1` does not. And testing with `*b` changed to `b[5]` shows the number with `static` matters, not just its presence (`static 4` has the test, `static 6` does not).

Comment: So does [mainline Clang 10.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/KM5Wda). But GCC 10.1 does not.

Comment: The point about optimization makes sense. I guess what is "significant" is relative/subjective ;)

Comment: A runtime constraint means nothing more nor less than that nothing an implementation may do if the conditions are violated would render the implementation non-conforming.  There are many situations where it would be useful for some implementations to use constraints for diagnostics, some to use them for optimization, and some to regard them as avenues for "conforming language extension" by processing code usefully in situations that would be useful for some tasks on some platforms, even if they wouldn't be useful for all tasks on all platforms.